# PHP Array ForEach SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, foreach

I am trying to use a FOREACH loop to query a database based on each value in the $userid array below. I am also looping through the $grade array as I need the corresponding value for the sql query to then put into a HTML table.

```
//Decode JSON file to an Object
$json_d = json_decode(file_get_contents("results.json"));

//Provisional Array Setup for Grades
$grade = array();
$userid = array();

foreach($json_d->assignments[0]->grades as $gradeInfo) { 
    $grade[] = $gradeInfo->grade;
    $userid[] = $gradeInfo->userid;
}

//Server Details
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "moodle";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "<table><tr><th>First Name </th><th>Last Name </th><th>Grade </th></tr>";

foreach($userid as $id) {
    foreach($grade as $grd) {
        $sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM mdl_user WHERE id='$id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row["firstname"]. "</td><td>" . $row["lastname"]. "</td><td> " . $grd . "</td></tr>";
        }

        } else {
            echo "ERROR!";
        }

    }
}

echo "</table>"; 


mysqli_close($conn);
```

I have checked the $grade and $userid array and they do contain the correct values however running the PHP file I only get the first record outputted in the table. E.G.

FirstName LastName Grade
Student   1        85

Whereas I need the other 2 records that are supposed to appear.

Comment: ANd what are the values of `$userid`? Have you checked that users with these ids exist in your table?

Comment: $userid is an array, having the following values [0]=3,[1]=4,[2]=5. I can confirm these values exist in the database (table)

Comment: Are you sure? can you please put a `var_dump($userid);` before this line `$servername = "localhost";` and share the output with us? Also having 2 nested `foreach` loops is wrong and will output wrong result for you.

Comment: @EhsanT var_dump returns: array (size=3)
  0 => int 3
  1 => int 4
  2 => int 5

Comment: Two questions: 1- Is the firstname really "Student" and lastname "1"? 2- Are you sure you get 1 row and not 9 rows?!

Comment: @EhsanT Yes I am sure, I created the users specifically for this purpose. Yes

Comment: The PHP script works when I directly execute however if I use jQuery POST then only the first record on the table appears

Comment: You know that your current question has nothing to do with `ajax`?!